# Multiple sliders with Very Simple Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm trying to use the **[Very Simple Slider](https://codepen.io/doodlemarks/pen/aFcly)** for my future website, but I have an issue with it when I want to have several sliders on the same page.

When I duplicate all properties in the HTML/CSS/JS and change the names to create a new slider, it does create a new slider but the controlling arrows do not work anymore. Well, they work, but for one slider only. I know it might be something like a JS issue, but as I am not a developer, I can't find the problem.

If you can help me finding a solution - and also a way to shorten both CSS and JS, that would be super cool, because I will have to use this slider ten times on the same page through css modals.

Oh, and here are my codes.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });

  var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
  var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  $('#slider').css({
    width: slideWidth,
    height: slideHeight
  });

  $('#slider ul').css({
    width: sliderUlWidth,
    marginLeft: -slideWidth
  });

  $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

  function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: +slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: -slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  $('a.control_prev').click(function() {
    moveLeft();
  });

  $('a.control_next').click(function() {
    moveRight();
  });


  var slideCount = $('#slider2 ul li').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider2 ul li').width();
  var slideHeight = $('#slider2 ul li').height();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  $('#slider2').css({
    width: slideWidth,
    height: slideHeight
  });

  $('#slider2 ul').css({
    width: sliderUlWidth,
    marginLeft: -slideWidth
  });

  $('#slider2 ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider2 ul');

  function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider2 ul').animate({
      left: +slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider2 ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider2 ul');
      $('#slider2 ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  function moveRight() {
    $('#slider2 ul').animate({
      left: -slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider2 ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider2 ul');
      $('#slider2 ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  $('a.control_prev2').click(function() {
    moveLeft();
  });

  $('a.control_next2').click(function() {
    moveRight();
  });

});
```

```css
#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev,
a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover,
a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#slider2 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider2 ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider2 ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev2,
a.control_next2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev2:hover,
a.control_next2:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev2 {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next2 {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option2 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev">
    <</a>
      <ul>
        <li>SLIDE 1</li>
        <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
        <li>SLIDE 3</li>
        <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
      </ul>
</div>

<div id="slider2">
  <a href="#" class="control_next2">></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev2">
    <</a>
      <ul>
        <li>SLIDE 1</li>
        <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
        <li>SLIDE 3</li>
        <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Rather use some other slideshow/plugin... This one have serious bug, when you try to use 'autoplay' option, turn it on and off, and see... there are better ones, for sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are declaring `moveLeft` and `moveRight` twice just rename the one for the slider2 and it will work

**EDIT:**

The approach you are using is not recommended as you have to change the source code **(js and css)** every time you need to add a new slider on the same page, you should look into how to create plugins,that would help you learn how to create a generic slider, meanwhile a good example of slider like [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) would be a good choice to use, but since you are trying to learn and want to clear the bug thats why adding the snippet and proposing an answer.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });

  var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
  var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  $('#slider').css({
    width: slideWidth,
    height: slideHeight
  });

  $('#slider ul').css({
    width: sliderUlWidth,
    marginLeft: -slideWidth
  });

  $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

  function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: +slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: -slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  $('a.control_prev').click(function() {
    moveLeft();
  });

  $('a.control_next').click(function() {
    moveRight();
  });


  var slideCount = $('#slider2 ul li').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider2 ul li').width();
  var slideHeight = $('#slider2 ul li').height();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  $('#slider2').css({
    width: slideWidth,
    height: slideHeight
  });

  $('#slider2 ul').css({
    width: sliderUlWidth,
    marginLeft: -slideWidth
  });

  $('#slider2 ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider2 ul');

  function moveLeft2() {
    $('#slider2 ul').animate({
      left: +slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider2 ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider2 ul');
      $('#slider2 ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  function moveRight2() {
    $('#slider2 ul').animate({
      left: -slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider2 ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider2 ul');
      $('#slider2 ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  $('a.control_prev2').click(function() {
    moveLeft2();
  });

  $('a.control_next2').click(function() {
    moveRight2();
  });

});
```

```css
#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev,
a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover,
a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#slider2 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider2 ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider2 ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev2,
a.control_next2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev2:hover,
a.control_next2:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev2 {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next2 {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option2 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#." class="control_next">&gt;</a>
  <a href="#." class="control_prev">
    &lt;</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="slider2">
  <a href="#." class="control_next2">&gt;</a>
  <a href="#." class="control_prev2">
    &lt;</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG, thanks! I know this sounds stupid but I've spent my day going crazy with it... Thank you!

Comment: lol it's alright, it happens, glad i could help but you should not use it you should use a generic slider which supports multiple instances on a page like this one http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: @SamaBalaYam both are working its just moving to upper slider when clicked see in full page view, you should see the code before you point out the mistake

Comment: That's not the way to go, to copy paste JS or CSS code - per - slider.

Comment: i agree @RokoC.Buljan and thats what i said in my first reply in comments that he should not use it , but he is trying to learn and the original requirement was to fix the code he is working on and i never copy pasted if you see the original post i just renamed the functions that were declared twice

Comment: you should see what the OP requires before you downvote , obviously I won't create a slider here for him, anyway cheers

Comment: yes @MuhammadOmerAslam you are right, its just the bug fix. dont know why such people downvote the answer

Comment: its ok @SamaBalaYam chill out we should be nice and shouldn't forget what we are here for, and that is to help out each other.

Comment: yes we should. pata nhi kya samjtay hen ye log apnay ap ko.

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadOmerAslam for the suggestion, I'm having a look at the sliders and they seem to be pretty cool and easy!

Comment: yeah go for it and post your question if you get into trouble @GaelGL

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yeah I know I shouldn't copy paste like that, that's why I'm also asking for a shorten version of the code, as I don't know how to do it for this :/

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Thank you for the link you gave me! I've found a seriously better option!

Comment: my pleasure glad i could help

Comment: @GaelGL can you select the right answer so that others facing similar problem could benefit from this post too.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the working example. but you should make it more generalize so that you can add multiple sliders if you want.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });

  var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
  var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  $('#slider').css({
    width: slideWidth,
    height: slideHeight
  });

  $('#slider ul').css({
    width: sliderUlWidth,
    marginLeft: -slideWidth
  });

  $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

  function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: +slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: -slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  $('a.control_prev').click(function() {
    moveLeft();
  });

  $('a.control_next').click(function() {
    moveRight();
  });

var slide2Count = $('#slider2 ul li').length;
 var slide2Width = $('#slider2 ul li').width();
 var slide2Height = $('#slider2 ul li').height();
 var slider2UlWidth = slide2Count * slide2Width;
 
 $('#slider2').css({ width: slide2Width, height: slide2Height });
 
 $('#slider2 ul').css({ width: slider2UlWidth, marginLeft: - slide2Width });
 
    $('#slider2 ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider2 ul');

    function moveLeftS2() {
        $('#slider2 ul').animate({
            left: + slide2Width
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider2 ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider2 ul');
            $('#slider2 ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRightS2() {
        $('#slider2 ul').animate({
            left: - slide2Width
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider2 ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider2 ul');
            $('#slider2 ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev2').click(function () {
        moveLeftS2();
    });

    $('a.control_next2').click(function () {
        moveRightS2();
    });


});
```

```css
#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev,
a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover,
a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#slider2 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider2 ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider2 ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev2,
a.control_next2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev2:hover,
a.control_next2:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev2 {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next2 {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option2 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="control_next">></a>
  <a href="javascript:;" class="control_prev">
    <</a>
      <ul>
        <li>SLIDE 1</li>
        <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
        <li>SLIDE 3</li>
        <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
      </ul>
</div>

<div id="slider2">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="control_next2">></a>
  <a href="javascript:;" class="control_prev2">
    < </a>
      <ul>
        <li>SLIDE 21</li>
        <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 22</li>
        <li>SLIDE 23</li>
        <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 24</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What if the number of slideshows in unknown? (We should not copy-paste CSS and JS anyways. Use classes and plugins)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it just the fix of the bug. i have mentioned it that you should make it more generalize, generic  so that you can add multiple if you want without writing css and js code for each slider